# UKMCs- United Kingdom Mathematical Challenges

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Mathematical Challenges are a series of maths challenges run by Leeds University in the UK. Are questions regarding the rules allowed to be asked in Maths SE?

Comment: What the answer has said, I would generally agree. However, another point I would like to add is finding users that do know about the UKMT challenges and talking to them in chat. As a matter of fact, I am a current UKMT volunteer and a avid solver of their problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [United Kingdom Mathematics Trust](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/) (which organises these challenges) seems to have a pretty good website, which has information about [rules for individual challenges](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/individual-competitions/#ancRules), a good [frequently asked questions](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/about-us/faq/) page, and [contact information](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/about-us/contact-us/).

I imagine that going through the UKMT would be a much more effective way of getting your questions about their challenges answered, as opposed to a hodge-podge of users on Mathematics Stack Exchange, including a very large percentage who have never heard of this before, and have no formal connection to it.

I would hazard that questions asked about the rules of these challenges would not be altogether welcome on our site. Our [site scope](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't formally include such "meta-mathematical" concerns.